# HTML content rewrite in python

Tags: python, html, css

I'm having some issues rewriting HTML text. I want to change my Text.

For Example:

```
<p>
Some Text
</P>
```

I cant output like this: `<p>This this some text</p>`

**or**

```
<ol>
<li>My Elm<li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li>My Elm<li>
</ul>
```

Output should be like this:

```
<ol>
<li>This is my elm<li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li>This is my elm<li>
</ul>
```

**I want to change only the text object and then put the same HTML.**

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us your [mre].

Comment: Does this help my problem? EHh??

Comment: In any case - it would help everyone to understand your question more easily and perhaps also to be able to reproduce it directly. For you, this would result in targeted answers that would help you to solve your problem.

Comment: @AbhijitMondal I'm sorry but your question is unclear, no need to make a cheeky comment to baduker they're just trying to help. I'm guessing you want to make HTML text variable. In that case you need to give an "id" to your HTML tags and write JavaScript. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById for example.

Comment: Actually, I want to split all elements into a list. For Exmaple:

Comment: ["<p>Some text</p>", "<ol><li>My elm</li></ol>"] Now I want to loop over and change text only.

Comment: I didn't get how to split elements.

Comment: Take the first comment to heart, invest a few minutes of reading and improve your question with the relevant information - The comments are not the best place for this, if only for reasons of lack of visualisation. Would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cause question is not that clear and needs some improvement - I would point with [`BeautifulSoups`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) [`replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) in a direction.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<ol>
<li>My Elm</li>
</ol>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.ol.li.string.replace_with('Some other text ...')

soup
```

##### Output

```
<ol>
<li>Some other text ...</li>
</ol>
```